# How To Trace user if Ip is dynamic

Tags: php, ip

I want to keep track of users who registers from same IP on my website. I am using following code to get the IP of user

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

But I noticed that IP address keeps changing. Is there any other way to track users?

Comment: I don't know If I like trusting `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` at all in this context.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Function to get the client ip address
function get_client_ip_server() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}
echo get_client_ip_server();
```

Comment: As additional information `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can contain comma seperated ip addresses, explode on comma, trim, and pick the first entry in the set.

Comment: @Awais Mustafa will it returns same value even on dynamic IPs?

Comment: This is some boiler plate code (which I suspect you've copy/pasted without attribution) which attempts to get the real IP of the user even if they are using a proxy server. It does absoultely nothing to deal with users having dynamically allocated IP addresses which the question is asking about.

Comment: i did not copy pasted it. I used it in my project and it was working perfect for my usage. So down vote is not good.